# GNU make: WithEnv variable of jenkins pipeline is not accessible inside shell

Tags: gnu-make

```
export INCLUDE_WEBKIT2:=$(shell PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${WEBKIT_SDK}/pkgconfig pkg-config --define-variable=WEBKIT_SDK=${WEBKIT_SDK} --cflags webkit2gtk-4.0 2>/dev/null)
$(info Deepak1 INCLUDE_WEBKIT2 in SSCommon is $(INCLUDE_WEBKIT2))
```

Here ${WEBKIT_SDK} value is correctly printed in makefile and pkgconfig path is also correct still i see $(INCLUDE_WEBKIT2) as empty in response. Can anyone help please. having linux environment.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this bit of makefile so the problem must be something we can't see here.  I recommend that first, you remove the `2>/dev/null` from your command so you can actually see any error messages that might get printed.  Second please show (via cut and paste) the exact command you typed and the exact output you got.

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist for the reply after removing 2>/dev/null i can see the PKG_CONFIG_PATH is not set properly because ${WEBKIT_SDK} is not accessible inside shell. ${WEBKIT_SDK} is being set from jenkins withEnv like  withEnv(['MYTOOL_HOME=/usr/local/mytool']) . Not sure how to make ${WEBKIT_SDK} accessible inside shell. Tried with $(WEBKIT_SDK) also

Comment: You may need to set the var to shell. Can you show you call make in Jenkins withEnv ?

Comment: If the `WEBKIT_SDK` environment variable needs to be set to invoke `pkgconfig`, not just used in the command line as part of `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, and you're setting it as a variable in your makefile, then you need to add `export WEBKIT_SDK` to your Makefile.  Makefile variables are not automatically exported into the environment of processes that make invokes.

Comment: export WEBKIT_SDK_PATH:=${WEBKIT_SDK}
export INCLUDE_WEBKIT2:=$(shell PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${WEBKIT_SDK_PATH}/pkgconfig pkg-config --define-variable=WEBKIT_SDK=${WEBKIT_SDK_PATH} --cflags webkit2gtk-4.0 2>/dev/null) is this fine?

Comment: Do i need to use ${WEBKIT_SDK_PATH} as $${WEBKIT_SDK_PATH} in shell?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for responding. I got this fixed. I was setting the Jenkins variable WEBKIT_SDK in Master Jenkins since scope of that variable was global and the agent (Slave) running was unable to read that variable in the shell. I have changed the scope from global to agent scope and everything works.